# autocmd event to execute a command on :wq - vimscript?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to execute `system("cp /home/currently_opened_file.txt /somewhere/else")` when I exit vim with `:wq`. Is there an autocmd event for that? Or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

The OP noted in comments that this combination did exactly what was wanted (execute the command only on `:wq`).

```
:autocmd BufWritePost * :autocmd VimLeave * :!cp % /somewhere/else
```

**Original answer**:

You can hook the `BufWritePost` event. This will run the command on **every** write, not only when you use `:wq` to leave the file.

```
:autocmd BufWritePost * :!cp % /somewhere/else
```

I suppose you could try hooking the `BufDelete` event *(before deleting a buffer from the buffer list)*, but that seems like it would be problematic, as buffers are used for more than file editors. They are also used for things like quicklists, the help viewer, etc.

There are some events that take place when you are quitting, which could be an option.

```
QuitPre        when using :quit, before deciding whether to quit
VimLeavePre    before exiting Vim, before writing the viminfo file
VimLeave       before exiting Vim, after writing the viminfo file
```

You can see the full list using `:help autocmd-events`.

Also note that you can restrict what matches the event. For instance, if you only want this to happen for HTML files and CSS files, you could use this:

```
:autocmd QuitPre *.html,*.css :!cp % /somewhere/else
```

I suspect you will need to experiment and see what works for you.

Comment: Hey, Dan. It will work with `:w` as well and I don't want that because it will be executed at every save of file. I want an event to work only with `:wq`. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. I hooked `BufWritePost` with `VimLeave`.  `:autocmd BufWritePost * :autocmd VimLeave * :!cp % /somewhere/else`

Comment: Cool, I will put that in the answer since it did exactly what you were after

Comment: Note that this will create one autocmd per write, so you'll end up with many identical copy commands! If this is only about a single file, you can avoid that with an `:augroup`: `:autocmd BufWritePost * augroup DuplicateWrite | execute 'autocmd! VimLeave * :!cp % /somewhere/else' | augroup END`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to automatically cascade the writing of a file to another location. My [DuplicateWrite plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4722) provides comfortable commands to set up such. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

```
:DuplicateWrite /somewhere/else
```

Comment: Thanks, that will come in handy.