# Vim: replacing string when saving and exiting

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have this autocommand at the moment:

```
autocmd Bufwritepre,filewritepre *.py exe ":silent! 1," . 20 . "g/Last Modified :.*/s/Last Modified :.*/Last Modified : " .strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z(%Z)")
```

Basically, replaces a certain string in my header. It writes the date of the last modification in the header of the file.

It works but it's annoying since it's triggered every time I save the file. I would like to trigger it only when I save AND leave the file.

From this question: [autocmd event to execute a command on :wq - vimscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100915/autocmd-event-to-execute-a-command-on-wq-vimscript)

I got something like:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.py :autocmd VimLeave *.py :! exe ":silent! 1," . 20 . "g/Last Modified :.*/s/Last Modified :.*/Last Modified : " .strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z(%Z)")
```

It doesn't work and when exiting vim I get some error message. Probably because the string substitution was originally done "internally" with vim commands, and now I try to do it with bash commands?

Could you help me solve this please?

EDIT:

Here is how my header looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Creation Date : 2018-11-27 14:55:00 +0100(CET)

* Last Modified : 2018-11-27 15:52:57 +0100(CET)

* Created By : JPFrancoia https://github.com/JPFrancoia

* Description :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
```

Comment: Thinking outside the box: How about writing a small wrapper for vim that handles the files after vim has quit (and if the conditions are met)?

Comment: Does [this](https://0x0.st/s03O.txt) do what you want?

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I missing something?:x

Comment: [It works on my machine](https://imgur.com/a/WplMIVa), when I start Vim with no other custom configuration: `$ vim -Nu /tmp/vimrc -O /tmp/vimrc /tmp/py.py`.
Btw, it can be [simplified](https://0x0.st/s03w.txt) a little.
If it doesn't work, you may have some custom configuration which interferes, or I have misunderstood your question, and was not trying the code on the right kind of text. If you could provide a simple example of file on which you're working, it would help.

Comment: I tried with no custom config (I think, I ran the same command as you with your snippet in the /tmp/vimrc). It didn't work :/ I added my header in my initial question.

Comment: I can confirm that the code works on the text you provided. In the gif, [the time switches](https://imgur.com/a/M3X8rwU) from `15:52:57` to `16:32:41` after I write the buffer and leave it.
I'm sorry it doesn't work on your machine, and I don't understand why. In case it helps, I'm using Vim version `8.1` with the patches up to `538`. Maybe updating Vim (if possible) would help, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Btw, right after starting Vim, if you execute `:au monitor_python_change` is there an output (you should see 2 autocmds)? And after writing a python buffer, if you execute `:au update_timestamp`, is there an output (you should see 1 autocmd listening to `BufLeave`).
Finally, if you execute `sil! 1/Last Modified : \zs.*/s//\=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z(%Z)")/`, in your python buffer, does it update the time (it should)?

Comment: Yes to your 3 commands. Ok now I understand what you mean, it indeed works. Leaving the buffer updates the timestamp, indeed. That's partly what I want. When I save AND quite a file (:x or :wq), I want the timestamp to be updated as well. If it could work on top of leaving the buffer (like what your snippet does), it would be amazing!

Comment: The snippet doesn't work, because when you execute `:x` or `:wq`, Vim doesn't fire `BufWritePre`, so the autocmd is not executed. Your initial autocmd, in the OP, should suffer from the same issue since it also listens to `BufWritePre`.
When you execute `:x`, Vim fires `QuitPre`, `BufLeave`, `WinLeave`, `BufWinLeave`, `BufHidden`. You could try `QuitPre`. This would give [this snippet](https://0x0.st/s0YH.txt).

Comment: That's much better, that's something like that I need. The only problem with the latest snippet is that the timestamp is updated when I quit the file, regardless if there was a change or not. Is it possible to add a test to check if the file changed? If it didn't change, the timestamp shouldn't be updated when we quit the file.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://0x0.st/s0g5.txt).

Comment: I think `let l:modified = &mod` and `if a:when is# 'now' && l:modified` ? It seems to do what I want.

Comment: Post an answer and I'll accept it, if you think what i just commented is valid. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
augroup monitor_python_change
    au!
    au QuitPre *.py call s:update_timestamp('now', 'on_QuitPre')
    au BufWritePre,FileWritePre *.py call s:update_timestamp('later', 'on_BufLeave')
augroup END

fu! s:update_timestamp(when, on_what) abort
    if a:when is# 'now'
        sil! au! update_timestamp
        sil! aug! update_timestamp
        if a:on_what is# 'on_QuitPre' && !&l:modified
            return
        endif
        sil! 1/Last Modified : \zs.*/s//\=strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z(%Z)')/
    else
        augroup update_timestamp
            au!
            au BufLeave * call s:update_timestamp('now', 'on_BufLeave')
        augroup END
    endif
endfu
```

If the code doesn't update your timestamp, you may need to change the substitution command:

```
"      ┌ pattern used in the next substitution command (`//` = last used pattern)
"      ├───────────────────┐
sil! 1/Last Modified : \zs.*/s//\=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z(%Z)")/
"    ├──────────────────────┘
"    └ range of the substitution command
"      (after the first line of the buffer,
"       look for the next line containing `Last Modified : `)
```

Maybe replace its pattern and/or its range.

If the code sometimes updates your timestamp, while it shouldn't, you may need to alter the condition inside `s:update_timestamp()`:

```
if a:on_what is# 'on_QuitPre' && !&l:modified
    return
endif
```

The current condition prevents the substitution from being performed when the function was called from `QuitPre` (`a:on_what is# 'on_QuitPre'`), and the buffer is not modified (`!&l:modified`).

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problem

The problem here is that while events like `BufWritePre` are always triggered when the current buffer is active (as you're currently in the process of `:write`), events like `VimLeave` are (or rather may be, depending on how you exit Vim) triggered outside of the scope of the current buffer. You could have edited multiple (Python or other) files in tabs, the argument list, split windows, etc. On `VimLeave`, you would have to locate all those buffers again, and explicitly iterate over them; the `:autocmd` mechanism won't do that for you.

A better trigger would be `BufUnload` or `BufDelete`, as this is fired once for each buffer. However, even there are complications, as [`:help BufUnload`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufUnload) explains:

> NOTE: When this autocommand is executed, the current buffer `%` may be different from the buffer being unloaded `<afile>`. Don't change to another buffer or window, it will cause problems!

While it's not possible to `:write` another buffer without switching to it, you can very well quit other buffers (e.g. via `:[N]bdelete` or `:qall`). As you're not allowed to switch to the affected (dying) buffer, using `:substitute` is out of the question. You could use the lower-level [`readfile()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#readfile%28%29) and [`writefile()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#writefile%28%29), with the filespec of the buffer obtained via `expand('<afile>:p')` and the manipulation via [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29). Or do the timestamp manipulation entirely outside Vim via [`system()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) and an external shell command.

#### Discussion

As you can see, switching from updates on every save to updating only on leaving Vim / the buffer sounds simple, but is very hard to implement (done right - you can bungle something together if you're only editing single files in a Vim session, for example). I'd rather stay with the original design, and work on the "annoying" part. With a robust implementation (that e.g. does not clobber the current search pattern and window view, as your simple solution does), this is very natural, and many people use such functionality. In fact, you can use my [AutoAdapt plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4654), or any of the alternatives that are listed on its plugin page (or other plugins I was not aware of found on [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/), or elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'll work on the annoying part. I found a nice snippet http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time in the section Automatically update timestamps. The only downside is that when I modify a file and save, if I press "u" to cancel the change, vim jumps to the header and cancel the last timestamp change. "u" again and it cancels the change I really want to cancel. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: It might be possible to use `:undojoin` to combine the timestamp update with the previous change, but I would find that unnatural. Unfortunately, Vim needs to track _every_ change in its undo list, so there's no way around that.

Comment: Maybe by deleting the last entry in the undo history?

Comment: You can't modify the undo history without also affecting the buffer. Vim needs to traverse it in both directions for undo / redo to work.

Comment: Ok then I need to find another way. When I press "u" multiple times, it's very annoying to see Vim jump to the beginning of the file, then back to where I did my changes, multiple times. You said I could handle the timestamp outside of Vim. Probably something like sed would do the job. sed is quite easy, but once again, how do I get the file I'm writing into when I do :wq or :x ?

Comment: I ended up with something like this: ```":autocmd BufWritePost * :autocmd VimLeave * :! sed -ei "s/Last Modified :.*/Last Modified : "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"/g"" expand('<afile>:p'); sleep 10```But vim answers: ```zsh:1: number expected```

Comment: @Rififi. I don't see either how we could avoid the multiple _undo_s, and seeing the cursor jump to the line where the timestamp is -- unless we merge the date change with some other event, which doesn't sounds to be a good idea.
Note that another problem that needs solving is to avoid changing the timestamp when we restore the file to its original version. I do this by testing `ut.save_last <= ut.save_cur` (given `let ut = undotree()`).